# Problems with self.transport.write() for Twisted TCP client in Python

Tags: python, twisted

I have a very basic twisted server/client setup in python.

server.py:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echo(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        print("Connection made")

    def connectionLost(self):
        print("Connection lost")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print("Received data")
        print(data)
        self.transport.write(data)


class EchoFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo(self)


def main():
    PORT = 9009 #the port you want to run under. Choose something >1024
    endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, PORT)
    endpoint.listen(EchoFactory())
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

client.py:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol

class Greeter(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        print('sending message')
        self.transport.write("MESSAGE %s\n" % msg)
        print('message sent')

def gotProtocol(p):
    p.sendMessage("Hello")
    reactor.callLater(1, p.sendMessage, "This is sent in a second")
    reactor.callLater(2, p.transport.loseConnection)

PORT = 9009
point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", PORT)
d = connectProtocol(point, Greeter())
d.addCallback(gotProtocol)
print('running reactor')
reactor.run()
```

The server works just fine as I've pinged it with a Telnet client and receive the expected response.  However when I try and run client.py it gets stuck at "self.transport.write("MESSAGE %s\n" % msg)".  Or at least I assume it does as the last thing printed to console is 'sending message'.

I've searched for days but can't seem to figure out what's wrong (I'm rather new to networking).  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm using Python 3 and running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get stuck at `self.transport.write("MESSAGE %s\n" % msg)` it actually fails there. `Transport.write` only accepts `bytes`. Encode the string and it should work.

```
class Greeter(Protocol):

    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        print('sending message')
        self.transport.write(("MESSAGE %s\n" % msg).encode('utf8'))
        print('message sent')
```

Comment: After a certain version of Python and/or Twisted, "utf8" is the default encoding, so you can just use `encode()`. I can't remember which it is, but there you go.